# Male cat keeps trying to mate with female kittens

Tags: cats

Our story starts around a few months ago when a female cat gave birth to a 4 kittens in our backyard. At the time we didn't know what to do so we called RSPCA and asked them what we should do and they told us "the mother cat will take care of the kittens just leave them alone and they will go away", however my mother didn't want to leave them alone because she thought they would starve and she started buying food for them and the mother.

When the cats started opening their eyes this orange tomcat that walks around our neighbourhood randomly started coming to us and eating the food, at the time we thought nothing of it. However one day he decided to take one of the kittens overnight, (we know he did it because he was trying to accomplish it all day but we kept stopping him). We ended up thinking that he had eaten the kitten and we thought we could do nothing about it. One month later he comes back and starts to do this thing where he goes on top of the mother cat and bites her neck (mating I assume) However the mother cat doesn't allow him to do this and she usually walks away or fights him off.

Fast forward another month and now he is trying to do the same thing with the KITTENS! WHERE HE BITES THEIR NECK AND JUMPS ON THEIR BACK (again I assume this is mating).Roughly about 2 weeks ago he took another one of the kittens overnight however this one ended up coming back on its own. We always shoo him away. Recently the mother cat has stopped spending less time with her kittens and going away more and sometimes doesn't come back for a few nights
We all assumed this was to get away from the male tomcat.

This morning he came back and started doing the thing where jumps on their back and starts biting the kittens necks again (one of the kittens has gotten to the point where the fur has started falling off and you can see some of his skin on his neck which is really disturbing and worrying). The mother cat has gotten to the point where she always runs away when she sees the tomcat and doesn't come back for a bit

We are really worried for the kittens and don't want them getting pregnant and having litter at such a young age. You are probably wondering why we haven't just brought the kittens into our house however when we do that they just hide behind the fridge or go into a really dark corner with wires which is really dangerous. What should we do? Is there people we can call to come take the cats away? We live in the UK so if you can give us any UK related homes or something to come take the kittens away. We are worried almost everyday.

Comment: if this message ever reaches you... I just want to say, tomcat is a synonym for male cat, so you don't have to specify.

Answer (score 4):

Most female cats reach puberty and have their first heat cycle between five and nine months of age, occasionally earlier... just as human puberty occurs before the body is fully adult. You should talk to you vet about getting the cats neutered; that will mostly eliminate the mounting problem and completely eliminate the risk of more kittens.

Personally, I'd try to get the older Tom and Queen fixed ***now**", and the kittens fixed at the earliest age/size your vet is willing to perform the operation. Obviously if the adults are someone else's cats you would need to talk to their owners about this.

Having said that: Mock mounting can also be a dominance display. My two nine-year-olds are both neutered, but every so often the boy will grab his sister's scruff. Since they aren't harming each other, and since she sometimes instigates this wrestling match, I'm mostly letting them handle it .

(She wants me to stop typing now...)

Answer (score 0):

I think he is showing dominance to the kittens. He maybe trying to get the females pregnant but they have to be 6 months to mates with a male.

Answer (score -3):

I have a tom and queen myself. I want to spay my queen, but she is currently pregnant. My vet told me to bring her in 1 month after she gives birth to be spayed, and we are neutering the tom now.

I also used to face the same problem with the female cat not wanting to mate and the male forcing her to. The best solution for this is neutering or spaying. One other funny solution is to regular spray some water when the male does this to the kittens, and then he will be too afraid to do it.

Comment: Spraying water is not enough to keep the tomcat away.